# SQL Server Report Builder - "Object moved to" message when connecting to SharePoint 2013 lists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

I am unable to connect SQL Server Report Builder 2012 to SharePoint 2013 to create reports from SharePoint lists. This is the error message that I get when trying to create DataSet

[image]

Report server database mode is Native, because it looks like SharePoint Integration mode cannot be set in 2012 version, and this option is not availabel when creating new report server database.

```
===================================

An error occurred when accessing the specified SharePoint list. The connection string might not be valid. Verify that the connection string is correct.  (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.ExecuteServiceRequest(ServiceRequest request)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.GetLists()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.SharePoint.SharePointTables.Refresh()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.SharePoint.QueryDesigner.Presenter.ValidateConnection()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.SharePoint.SharePointQueryDesigner.InitializeQueryDesigner()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.InternalQueryDesignerWrapper.InitializeDesigner()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.InternalQueryDesignerWithGenericModeWrapper.Initialize()

===================================

The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsites%2fjob1%2f_vti_bi%2fLists.asmx%2f_vti_bin%2fLists.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

--. (System.Web.Services)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPListService.GetListCollection()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetLists>b__0(SPListService listSvc)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPRemoteConnection.ExecuteServiceRequest(ServiceRequest request)
```

This is the data source configuration

[image: Data source configuration]
[image]

For authentication we use the same service account in execution account, and that is the one provided in this data source.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by extending web app in SharePoint Central Administration. New web app uses the same application pool but it is on different port, and uses **Basic Authentication**

It look like that Report Builder uses basic authentication and the web app must use basic authentication too.